# php function inside another function

Tags: php, function, return

I have a function and I am trying to call that inside another function. i haven't done much php, so please clarify  my question.

```
public function user($user)
{
if($user==''){
$this->logerror('not valid'); //this stores error in the db
return false;
}
}
```

I want to call the above function inside one main function, if I just do this way

```
public function main($username, $email) {
$this -> user($username);
//more code here to do something only if the user name is not empty
}
```

If i just do the main function like this, it stores the error saying "not valid" but the function continues. I understand that i am not returning anything so it does both the things, so how to stop the function if it's not valid username.

but if i just copy the content of the "user" function it works fine as it returns false. I assumed that calling the function user inside the main will do the same thing.

please advise.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just catch the return value and then do something with it

```
$result = $this->user($username);
if ($result === false) {
  return false; // or something else
} else {
  // Do something, if user() does not return 'false'
}
```

Comment: The `user()` method should be modified to return `true` if valid, for consistency's sake

Comment: Good point. However, I dont see any reason for the whole method, if in `main()` one can just use `if($user !== '') { /* do something */ } else { $this->logerror('not valid'); }`.

Comment: @kingcrunch, thanks for the quick reply, i tired what you said and it works fine.thanks.  i kind of did that by assigning it to a variable, but what is the purpose of having the condition check in the separate function "user" already..also, if($result ==== false) can return false only right? what can be something else? can i echo something? sorry by the time i posted there are comments. will read those.

Comment: @kincrunch, that user function will be called in other places. earlier i did by doing it directly inside the main function

Comment: @gan: if `$result` is false, `$result === false` is `true`. Dont know, what you mean by "echo something". Of course you can echo something. If you want to see the value of a variable, use `var_dump()`.

Comment: @phil brown - thanks but why it cannot be false inside the user function ? what kind of consistency you are talking about? is it a good practice to have as return true.?

Comment: @kingcrunch - when you said return false; // or something else i got doubt what else can be done if i just want to check result is false..

Comment: @gan: If you have a return value `false`, if something "went wrong" its just a logical consequence, that this should return `true`, if everything is fine. See functions/methods, that return boolean values, as a kind of question: "Is this username valid? yes/no". Here its more like "no" and then there is silence :) There is no answer for "yes"

Comment: @gan I dont know, what you are going to do there. I just guessed ^^ You can do everything you like. In my example I just return `false` to the caller. You can `echo` something, write into a log or whatever.

Comment: @KingCrunch And in PHP, silence (void) will be evaluated as `false` when using equality operators

Comment: @PHIL: A little bit more precise: "silence" (=> omitting `return`) will always "return" `null` :) In fact its just the same, except that `void` is only a pseudo-type in php (meaning "this method has no `return` statement" (against "this method returns `null`")). Its more or less only for documentation. However, `===` is the identity comparison, which will test the type of the variable also (`(false === null) === false`).

Comment: @KingCrunch Right you are. Wasn't saying your answer wouldn't work (because it does). As shown in the other answer, using an equality (not identical) comparison operator will probably yield unexpected results